# In table tennis, is it possible to play a ball in such a way that it does not bounce off the opponents half of the table?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

In table tennis you dont need to play over the net, the ball just has to hit the other half of the table. Is it possible to play the ball around the net so that it does not bounce off?

My friend and I were arguing about this. I said that the ball can only hit the table from the top, so it has to bounce back up. The only exception to his I could think of was if you hit the ball exactly and the same time it his the table so it does not drop and just rolls over the table with a single contact. That would only be possible in theory in my opinion.

He said with enough spin and deformation of the ball the downward movement can be translated to a forward movement so it does not bounce. Is that possible with humanly possible speeds and spins (what about superhuman speeds and spins?)?

Comment: maybe that would only happen if you deform it in such a way as to break the ball.

Comment: Aha! hit the ball from the side of the table, such that it won't pass over the net. make sure the ball will not bump the edge of the table, and the ball has almost only horizontal motion when it reaches the surface.

Comment: Something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNKn23i0hOg (at 1.20)

Comment: It is not happening in the video! If you put it on x0.5 you can hear it bouncing. It only looks that way because the ball is moving at a bad camera angle to see its vertical movement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like Andrei commented, here's another example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEJZsJvIN_Q. You're right that it needs to come from around the net and lower than the surface. It's incredibly difficult and rare, and even if it can never be done mathematically perfect, it can be close enough that you can't tell the difference.